# Set page color for double-double float

Tags: floats, color, afterpage

I have a custom command, comprising two instances of `\@dblfloat`. I'd like to change the page color on pages where this occurs. I can do this for a single instance of `\@dblfloat`, but not more.

In the following example, the first figure is coloured blue (correctly) but the subsequent figures are not. If I place `\pagecolor` without `\afterpage` before `\@dblfloat`, the page preceding the floats is also coloured.

(Note that in this example, I'm using a figure float to provide an MWE, but I'd like a solution for all floats -- including custom ones.)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{dblfigure}{
  \afterpage{\pagecolor{blue!50}}
    \@dblfloat{figure}  
}{
  \afterpage{\clearpage\nopagecolor}
    \end@dblfloat

}

\newcommand{\dblpagefigure}[2]{

    \@dblfloat{figure}
     % \pagecolor{blue!50} puts color too early
      #1
    \end@dblfloat
    \@dblfloat{figure}
      #2
    \end@dblfloat
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{dblfigure}
\caption{Some other figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{dblfigure}

\lipsum
Some text to avoid `\lipsum` taking up an exact page.

\lipsum

\dblpagefigure{
    \caption{Some figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
}{
    \caption{Another figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \afterpage{\clearpage\nopagecolor}
}

\lipsum
\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't turn blue when I test it

Comment: I am sorry, but still it doesn't

Comment: Hmmm, sorry this is causing difficulty, but on my machine when the line on line 19 is **not** commented out, I get page 6 and 7 colored blue, which is what I want, but also I get page 6 colored blue, which I don't. With the line commented out, pages 5-7 are not colored.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the previous page to the figures are also colored because of the way floats work in latex. See for instance the green page, it doesn't have that problem

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{dblfigure}{
  \pagecolor{blue!50}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
    \@dblfloat{figure} 
} {
  \end@dblfloat
}

\newenvironment{sglfigure}{
  \pagecolor{green!50}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}
  \begin{figure}
} {
  \end{figure}
}

\newcommand{\dblpagefigure}[2]{

    \begin{dblfigure}
      #1
    \end{dblfigure}
    % 
    \begin{dblfigure}
      #2
    \end{dblfigure}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{dblfigure}
\caption{Some other figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{dblfigure}

\lipsum
Some text to avoid `\lipsum` taking up an exact page.

\lipsum

\dblpagefigure{
  \caption{Some figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
}{
  \caption{Another figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\lipsum[1]
\begin{sglfigure}
\caption{Some other figure}
\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{sglfigure}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

[image]